# jackson json parser accepting empty single quotes for int primitives

Tags: java, json, jackson, primitive-types, single-quotes

I have defined a REST element in our project which contains attributes with primitive int & long . I am using Jersey 2.17 
During testing when I tried to pass a "" string, the REST client did not report any validation errors, but in the rest resource, I get the value of the primitive as the default value 0. This behavior is very odd as an empty string should not be accepted in this case. How do I make the request fail with validation errors.

```
My JSON request:
JSONObject employee = new JSONObject("{name : James}");     
rateLimiter.put("age", "");

Response :
POST -><http://134.141.206.113:8080/Employee     >
data: {"name":"James","age":""}
Status :201 output: {  
  "name" : "James",
  "age" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to check the payload's field for emptiness or null is by using the Jackson's annotations to skip these fields while deserializing. In this way, if a compulsory field is not present in the deserialized object then you can assume that the field was empty while the request was made.

Jackson's Annotations

1. @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
2. @JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)

Add them on top where the fields are declared in the DTO/entity class

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)
private int age = 0;

@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
private String name;
```

Comment: Srikanta thanks, but your response is very vague, I have mentioned I am  using jersey 2.17. I am looking for pointer  on any configuration with JSON mapper or probably custom deserializers.

Comment: @Nawaz I've updated the annotation which can help you for compulsory fields. Hope this helps

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I would like to fail the request. I need the client to get a validation error, the option you are giving will only exclude them. For my usecase the primitive fields in some entities are optional one which means the user can skip this but if he gives a value that should not be a empty String. I have many entities, I am looking for a solution to do it once instead of marking each attribute with the annotation. I tried custom serializer/deserializer, no luck, I will add the source. I would like to know if that is the only option.

Comment: You can send a validation error for PUT call by checking on the URL query parameter at the router. For a POST call you need to deserialize for validating and then send an error with HTTP 401. However if you do not want to deserialize it then you can use the https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath to check for a value associated with a field and then return HTTP 401. I believe you need to choose one of these options.